# Session variable gets lost between pages

Tags: php

I have numerous pages that I need to access a variable on. This variable is assigned a value when a user enters an ID into a form on accounts.php:

**account.php**

```
<form action="afterlog.php" class="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="amid" id = "amid" class="input" />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Go" />       
</form>
```

which posts the value 'amid' to afterlog.php

**afterlog.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
    $_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$account_manager_id;
    $account_manager_id = $_POST['amid'];
    header('Location: customer_view.php');
  }
?>
```

which checks the POST, assigns the session variable, and redirects rhe user to customer_view.php

**customer_view.php**

I need to use '$account_manager_id' in this page and all pages after. Here is how I am assigning it the value of the _SESSION variable:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$account_manager_id;
?>
```

Bu the value isn't being held on any of the pages, including customer_view.php. I know its passing to afterload.php because it prints out on that page, but its gone after that page.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no value assigned to the variable `$account_manager_id` at the time your are trying to put it into your session. **Enable proper error_reporting, NOW!**

Comment: 1. In afterlog.php you're assigning a variable to $_SESSION before actually setting that variable's value. 2. In customer_view.php you're overwriting the value in $_SESSION with what I assume is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: And your attempt at “assigning” the value in the customer_view script is nonsense as well – you want to get a value _out_ of the session, not to _overwrite_ the existing session value with another one (which is, of course, again undefined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to `$_SESSION['account_manager_id']` before `$account_manager_id` has any value in it. You just need to switch the order:

```
$_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$account_manager_id;
$account_manager_id = $_POST['amid'];
```

or simply:

```
$_SESSION['account_manager_id'] = $_POST['amid'];
```

Comment: What would I need to to to access 'account_manager_id' on the third page? Currently I have:$_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$account_manager_id;

Answer (score 0):

in afterlog.php

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
    $account_manager_id = $_POST['amid'];    
    $_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$account_manager_id;

    header('Location: customer_view.php');
  }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
    $_SESSION['account_manager_id']=$_POST['amid'];
    header('Location: customer_view.php');
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think my issue is how Im referencing the variable when Im using it again, which is in queries like this: "SELECT * FROM mgap_account_managers WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id' ";

Comment: or so $sql = "SELECT * FROM mgap_account_managers WHERE account_manager_id = ".$_SESSION['account_manager_id'];